# xpages: computed field display multiple values in listbox with onchange event

Tags: xpages

I would like to ask how to use the computed field to display listbox value?

My idea is there is a listbox and a computed field. In the listbox, I use partial update in the onchange event and the partial update id is computed field

I may post the code about the listbbox and the computed field here:

For the listbox:

```
<xp:listBox id="listBox2">
    <xp:selectItems>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.get("vs1");
}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="computedField1">
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:listBox>
```

For the computed field: In this part I have read this post: [How to get display text of combobox and not the alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23386111/how-to-get-display-text-of-combobox-and-not-the-alias) to learn how display the listbox value.

```
function getComponentLabel(componentId) {       
var select = getComponent(componentId); 
var value = select.getValue();
try {
    var list = select.getChildren();
    if (value) {
       for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { 
          if ((typeof list[i]).indexOf("SelectItems") > -1) {
              items = list[i].getValue();
              for (var k = 0; k < items.length; k++) {
                  if (items[k].getValue() === value) { 
                     return items[k].getLabel();
                  }
              }
           }  
           else if((typeof list[i]).indexOf("SelectItem") > -1) {
             if (list[i].getItemValue() === value) { 
                 return list[i].getItemLabel();
             }
          }
       }   
   }
} catch (e) {       
}
return value;
}

var dspValue = getComponentLabel("listBox1");//yes, it's listbox 1 not listbox2, if type listbox2, the computed field will show null (not sure why) 

return "The listbox selected value(s) is: " + dspValue;
```

So far when I run the code at the first time, I put the value in the listbox,  the computed field can display the selected value from the list box. But when I put multiple values in the listbox, the computed field can only show the latest value that I've put.

I have tried to use for loop in the computed field to get the selected values in list box:

```
var text="";
for (var i = 0; i < dspValue.length; i++)
{
    text += dspValue[i];
}
return "you select value is: " + text;
```

Then I run the code, I get the error message said the dspValue is null. I also try to display the dspValue.length without the for loop and get the same error.

Instead of use for loop, I don't have the idea to get all values from the listbox and show in the computed field.

How can I use the computed field to display all the selected values in the listbox? I appreciate for any advice please.

Comment: I would highly recommend you use your REAL NAME.  It makes interacting with the community a much better experience.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need the submittedValue of the component, see the answer of Paul Withers in the question, [xPage dateTime picker validation does not work on date change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569705/xpage-datetime-picker-validation-does-not-work-on-date-change)

Comment: Hello @Frank van der Linden, thank you for your suggestion. I read the post and tried your code from this [website](https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=getcomponentvalue) in the computed field. However, the computed field only return null for the result no matter I put the value in the listbox. I think maybe I misunderstand the coding and I would like to ask is if I put the `getSubmittedValue` in the code, the list box still need partial update the computed field?

Comment: Sorry, may I ask one more question please?  I am using domino designer 8.5.2, so do I need to concern about the version of the domino designer?

Comment: If you're doing Xpages development. You really should be on a MINUMIUM of 8.5.3 with update pack 1.  For designer and server.  And it's actually painful to write that.  In practice you should be on the latest version - 9.0.1 for your servers and designers.
8.5.2 came out in 2010.  That's SIX years old and going.  Any web technology needs to be kept update if for nothing else the security updates.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to simplify it and instead of a Computed Field, use a duplicate 'read-only' list box instead. This way the List Box's Read-Only renderer will do the heavy lifting of determining the appropriate Labels. You just need to make sure both listboxes have the same select values.

```
<!-- This is your List Box -->
<xp:listBox id="listBox1" value="#{viewScope.yourValue}" multiple="true">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Label One" itemValue="1"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Label Two" itemValue="2"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Label Three" itemValue="3"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="listBox2"></xp:eventHandler>
</xp:listBox>


<!-- This is instead of your 'Computed Field' -->
<xp:listBox id="listBox2" value="#{viewScope.yourValue}" readonly="true">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Label One" itemValue="1"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Label Two" itemValue="2"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Label Three" itemValue="3"></xp:selectItem>
</xp:listBox>
```

The only downside of this is that the readonly values are rendered as a vertical table with each label on each row. You may have preferred comma separated. 
You might be able to use the same concept with another read-only control that might support comma separated display or something you prefer.
or you could make a custom renderer but that is another kettle of fish!

Comment: Hello Cameron Gregor, thank you for your suggestion. I tried to use 'read -only' in the list box, however the list box becomes invisible.

Comment: just to clarify, I did not mean to make your original list box 'read-only' I meant (as above in the example) to have 2 list boxes, with the second list box being used instead of your computed field. The second list box is the one to be marked read-only.
A read-only list box will be invisible if there are no selected values.
Also looking at your question, your listbox is not bound to any value which is a bit strange, you would usually bind a list box to some sort of document field or scoped variable or managed bean property

Comment: The list boxes  work now. Sorry for the inconvenience that I have made. Thank you.

Comment: If you have your solution don't forget to accept this as the answer.